# Anyone know a way to get a profile of a ride from google?

Tags: bikeroutes

I'm considering adjusting my ride to work a bit - considering a change that will make it slightly longer, and probably a lot hillier.  But from looking at the route on google maps, I can't really tell, even with the terrain layer turned on.

Anyone know of a tool that will graph the profile of a route for me?

**Edit:** Ideally, I'd be able to just link the tool to my route on google, and not have to redraw it.

(The routes in question:  [Current route](http://goo.gl/maps/JLBW), [proposed route](http://goo.gl/maps/8PhC))

Comment: More hills = more interesting ride!

Comment: @darkcanuck - I'm with you there.  My commute is normally 14-15 miles.  I have a favorite route that is 19 because I go out of my way to ride up the closest big hill.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[GPS Visualizer](http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/) will do the job. From [this thread](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/maps/thread?fid=2f40cceacf857a700004911ff3df56d6&hl=en):

> Plan your route as normal in Google Maps.
>   Click on "link" above the top right corner of the map.
>   Copy the top link.
>
> Go to:  http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/profile_input
>
> Paste the GM link that you copied into the field titled:  "Or provide the URL of data on the Web:"

Answer (score 5):

[Bikely](http://www.bikely.com/) is an application built on top of google maps that supports importing GPX files and displaying height profiles.

Answer (score 5):

[MapMyRide.com](http://www.mapmyride.com) uses Google Maps in their web application, but I'm not sure if you can import an already-planned route from Google Maps:

[image: MapMyRide screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

The [VeloRoutes](http://veloroutes.org/bikemaps/) mashup with google.maps allows you to set your routes there and will give you elevation profiles and net.

This is a sample for one of your routes - http://veloroutes.org/r/60661

Answer (score 2):

[Gmaps Pedometer](http://www.gmap-pedometer.com/) is a pretty decent way to get an elevation map of your ride by plotting it on a Google map.